# Swift 3 How to create Date for a specific date

Tags: ios, swift, ckquery

In swift 2.3, I wrote a function that takes the date 6-01-16, converts it to NSDate, then utilizes that in a CKQuery. I'm not sure how to update this for Swift 3.

Here's my current code:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyymmdd"
    let olddate = formatter.date(from: "20160601")
    print(olddate)
```

This isn't working, how should I change my syntax?

Comment: How is it "not working"? Syntax error, wrong result? Note that your month format is wrong (it should be "MM") so this wouldn't work in Swift 2.3 either.

Comment: Ah, found the issue somewhere else. I'm trying to access the field "sortingDate" in a CKRecord which I know exists with "var prevFact = birdFacts[0].value(forKey: "sortingDate") as! Int". Is this syntax correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mm` is the format for minutes; you mean `MM` for months. Your `dateFormat` should be:

```
"yyyyMMdd"
```